# Accessing child form property in C# window's forms

Tags: c#

So I am trying to access a public member variable of my child form from its parent form.  The form has a public get property from which I am trying to access the variable.  Here is how the variable is defined in my child form:

```
    public partial class frmNewProduct : Form
{
    public Inventory _inventory { get; private set; }
```

Now let's switch pace and go to the parent form.  The instance of the child form is created below, and you can also see me trying to access _iventory's get property from that instance, but I receive compiler errors every time.

```
        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form newProduct = new frmNewProduct(_inventory, Mode.add);
        newProduct.Show();
        Inventory variable = newProduct._inventory;
    }
```

The compiler error reads the following:

Error   1   'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for '_inventory' and no extension method '_inventory' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does anyone know what is wrong here?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a type of the parent type Form. You need to declare it as the derived type, frmNewProduct. E.g:

```
frmNewProduct newProduct = new frmNewProduct(_inventory, Mode.add);
newProduct.Show();
Inventory variable = newProduct._inventory;
```

To clarify: You're adding a property to the type frmNewForm which inherits from Form. Form doesn't have the property, so you can't access it when declaring your variable as type Form.

Another example:

```
class BaseClass {
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Using the above code, you can't do this:

```
BaseClass base = new DerivedClass();
base.MyProperty = 12; // ERROR
```

..however, you can do this:

```
DerivedClass derived = new DerivedClass();
derived.MyProperty = 12; // Works
```

Comment: ohh. This is one of the quirks of inheritance coming into play here.  It is looking at the functions associated with the reference object and not the instance, right?

Comment: So here is a follow-up question to your great answer.  Is it considered good style to always have the parent form take data from the child, as opposed to having the child send data to the parent, or does the direction of data flow generally not matter?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not all that up with WinForms design styles, however based on what the built-in .NET dialogs do, the parent takes data from the child (for example, the ShowDialog() style). Also: remember to accept and upvote answers (not that I'm hungry for points!) :)